Does "call on" mean "utilize" in this context?
This is a definition from Oxford Languages for "appeal".

try to persuade someone to do something by calling on (a particular
principle or quality). "I appealed to his sense of justice"

Does "call on" mean "utilize" here?
call on
4. To utilize something, often a quality or skill.
The championship game was so intense that I really had to call on my mental toughness just to get through it. (Farlex Dictionary of Idioms)
Edit: Here's the link for Oxford Languages definition requested in the comments:
https://www.google.com/search?q=appeal+def&rlz=1C1CHBD_enPL1120PL1120&oq=appeal+def&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggAEEUYOzIGCAAQRRg7MgYIARAjGCcyDAgCECMYJxiABBiKBTINCAMQABiRAhiABBiKBTIMCAQQABhDGIAEGIoFMg0IBRAAGJECGIAEGIoFMgwIBhAAGEMYgAQYigUyBggHEEUYPNIBCDEyNjRqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

More like "invoking" when it is not something under one's control. I could "call on" what I believe is your sense of fair play, for example, I would say something that would have you consider the equities of the situation. I am not "wielding" your sense of fair play but summoning it, as it were.

The problem is that when you say to someone that "call on" in the definition of appeal means "invoke" and that person refers to a dictionary to check what "invoke" means they encounter
(cite or appeal to (someone or something) as an authority for an action or in support of an argument.). As you can see this makes it impossible to understand what it means because you start going in a circle.

But you're getting tunnel-vision and paying attention only to the verb. Surely the supplemental phrases give you some idea: "...as an authority for an action or in support of an argument."

It would help if you gave a link to a definition from Oxford Languages for "appeal"

"address oneself to (a principle or quality in someone) in anticipation of a favorable response."
"I appealed to his sense of justice"

"Adress oneself" as in "speak to someone"?

I am getting tunnel-vision. That's true. I am only trying to understand the meaning of "call on" in this particular context.

appeal to, summon, invoke, call on, address oneself to a principle or quality in someone.

But not to the person, rather to a character trait they possess.  It's a figurative use of call on and address.  "I appealed to (addressed myself to) his sense of justice."    It's like trying to reach someone's "better angels".

It happens quite often here that learners are stumped by figurative uses of  language.   To address oneself to X, is to speak such that if X is listening, X will respond.   Since one is not certain that X is listening, the verbs express a desire to summon X (call on, invoke).

To call [up]on (a particular principle or quality) usually implies bringing that principle / quality into play in some specific context, that you wouldn't normally use. So what you're calling on will often be some kind of "extreme" attribute, such as calling upon every ounce of one's strength to deal with some particularly challenging situation. Where "ounces" of strength are obviously metaphoric, as is the act of "calling on" them (you often metaphorically dig deep to access such attributes).

We even have the phrase "he summoned his courage" or "he summoned his last ounce of strength".  The ultimate origin of the metaphor is the summoning of gods to aid one in a time of need.

"Call on" is also used in another sense of "invoke" which is more literal. Just like some of you mentioned summon. But in this definition I belive "call on" means "to ask someone to do something":
call on (a deity or spirit) in prayer, as a witness, or for inspiration.

It's the same verb here but with a figurative meaning. To call on someone's sense of justice puts that sense of justice in the position of a deity who can respond to the person's need.  The deity is invoked, the person's "better angels" are invoked.  The figurative meaning is analogical.

An example of call on in the sense of utilise is "I often had to call on my training as a mathematician in order to solve electronic circuit design problems".

Google, Oxford Dictionary, 2.
make use of someone or something as a source of help.
"we are able to call on academic staff with a wide variety of expertise"

It's in the dictionary.

call on something=to make use of something
The championship game was so intense that I really had to make use of my mental toughness just to get through it.
Google, Oxford Dictionary,
2. make use of someone or something as a source of help. "we are able to call on academic staff with a wide variety of expertise"

Disregard the downvote. This answer is correct.
